# Python win32 Excel paste chart as bitmap (PasteSpecial)?

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I have several Excel charts which I would like to export as images with Python. Every chart is in a separate Excel file with only 1 sheet. This script works for almost all my charts:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test.xlsx")

xl.DisplayAlerts = False

chart = wb.Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1)
chart.CopyPicture()   

#Create new temporary sheet (after first sheet)
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After=xl.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)).Name="temp_sheet"
temp_sheet = xl.ActiveSheet

#Add chart object to new sheet.
cht = xl.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects().Add(0,0,chart.Width, chart.Height)

#Paste copied chart into new object
cht.Activate()      # dit is bij de topsheets nodig, anders plakt die een wit vlak... (bij trends en staafjes hoeft het niet)
cht.Chart.Paste()   

#Export image
cht.Chart.Export("C:\\test.png")

temp_sheet.Delete()
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close()

#Restore default behaviour
xl.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I have one chart however that cannot be exported... I get this error after the export function:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147287037), None)
```

The chart is copied to the temporary sheet, but export fails. In some old Excel-VBA code written for exporting this chart I see this line:

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Bitmap", Link:=False, 
DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

What is the Python equivalent? This:

```
cht.Chart.PasteSpecial(Format="Bitmap")
```

Is not working (AttributeError: '' object has no attribute 'PasteSpecial')

- edit -

The "clipboard comment" from Xukrao pointed me in another direction. With the help of this tutorial https://www.penwatch.net/cms/images_from_excel/ I used ImageGrab from PIL. Exporting the chart is working now! :)

```
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test.xlsx")

xl.DisplayAlerts = False

chart = wb.Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1)
chart.CopyPicture()   

#Create new temporary sheet (after first sheet)
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After=xl.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)).Name="temp_sheet"
temp_sheet = xl.ActiveSheet

xl.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial()

# Use PIL (python imaging library) to save from Windows clipboard
# to a file
wb.Worksheets(2).Pictures(1).Copy()
image = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
image.save('blabla.bmp','bmp')

#This line is not entirely neccessary since script currently exits without 
saving
temp_sheet.Delete()
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close()

#Restore default behaviour
xl.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct Python equivalent of

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Bitmap", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

would be this:

```
xl.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial(Format="Bitmap", Link=False, DisplayAsIcon=False)
```

Comment: I get this error when using that line: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', u'PasteSpecial  method of Worksheet class failed.', u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: The most likely cause of that error would be that the clipboard doesn't contain a chart yet.

Comment: I think the chart is in the clipboard, because when I use this line: xl.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial() the chart gets pasted on the temporary sheet. However not in the bitmap format, which I need...